# Tc, Tw and Tz operators with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, document, pdfbox

I tried to read an existing PDF document through **PDFBox**, extract the Tj operator and then change the spacing between words (Tw), characters (Tc), the horizontal spacing (Tz) in order to generate the modified document.
My problem is when i edit the modified document to read the modified file structure, the values of Tc, Tw, Tz operators are changed.
What is the solution to prevent this change?

let us consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        // TODO code application logic here   
           tes= new Test1();
           tes.CreatePdf(src);
           PDDocument doc ;
           doc = PDDocument.load("doc.pdf");
           List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();  
           for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++)  {
              PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);  
              PDStream contents = page.getContents();  
           COSDictionary dic= page.getCOSDictionary();
          System.out.println (dic.getCOSObject());
              PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
              parser.parse();  
              List tokens = parser.getTokens();  
              System.out.println(tokens);
                for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++)  
            {  
                  Object next = tokens.get(j); 
                     if (next instanceof PDFOperator)  {
                       PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;  
                    // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF  
                             if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj"))  
                    { 


            tokens.set(j-1, COSFloat.get("0.00416145"));
            tokens.set(j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tc"));
            tokens.add(++j, new COSString("he"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
             tokens.add(++j, COSFloat.get("0.001611215"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tc"));
            tokens.add(++j, COSFloat.get("0.0067152"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tw"));
             tokens.add(++j, new COSString("llo w"));
             tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
             tokens.add(++j, COSFloat.get("100.001410144"));
             tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tz"));
            tokens.add(++j, new COSString("orld"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));


                    }
                 }      
            }
                // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the page content stream.
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);  
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();  
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);  
            tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);  
            page.setContents(updatedStream);

    }

      doc.save("a.pdf"); 
      doc.close();  
    }

This file structure is obtained as follow:
6 0 obj
<<
/Length 8 0 R
>>
stream
BT
 /F0 12 Tf
 15 385 Td
 0.0041614501 Tc
 (he) Tj
 0.0016112149 Tc
 0.0067151999 Tw
 (llo w) Tj
 100.001411438 Tz
 (orld) Tj
 ET

endstream
endobj
```

Best regards,

Comment: What change are you talking about exactly? Isn't this simply floating point accuracy limitations you're seeing or am I missing some big change in the numbers?

Comment: [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168273): What is your X?

Comment: If you want to 100% control what ends up in the stream, you should build the bytes yourself. Otherwise you have to accept inaccuracies like that.

Comment: Firstly i would like to thank you all for your replies. Actually, let us consider that we set 2.6 as a value of (Tc) operator. So When we edit our document in order to show the file structure, we can notice that the value of (Tc) become 2.59999999 not 2.6. What is the problem? why i can't get the value 2.6 in the file structure ?

Comment: Unfortunately `COSFloat` internally uses a`float` to store is value.  You might want to derive your own `COSNumber` which  internally uses a String.